# conditional sum over a range python

Tags: python, sum, conditional-statements

I have created X as folowing

```
num_locations = 2
X= [ ]
for n in range(num_locations):
X.append([0 for j in range(num_locations)])
```

Now I want to sum these X[n][m] values for the case n != m . Such that the result should be like

```
X[0][1]+X[1][0]
```

Is there a way to do that with the sum formulation ?

```
X[n][m] for n in range(num_locations)for m in range(num_locations))
```

Comment: You're almost there: `sum(X[n][m] for n in range(num_locations) for m in range(num_locations) if n != m)`.

Comment: Fix the indentation. Also, if `num_locations` is greater than 2, you want the sum such as `X[0][1] + X[0][2] + X[1][0]...`?

Comment: Evert's your code works !! @Leva7 yes actually num_locations is equal to 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is effectively taking the sum of the non-diagonal elements of your 2D array. One option using Numpy could simply be to subtract the sum of the main diagonal ([`np.trace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html)) from the sum of the entire array.

```
num_locations = 2
X= [[1,2],[2,1]]

import numpy as np
s = np.sum(X) - np.trace(X)
print(s)
```

**Outputs**:

```
4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `enumerate`

```
>>> sum(o for i, a in enumerate(X) for j, o in enumerate(a) if i!=j)
0
```

Where `i` and `j` are *row* (1st dim) and *column* (2nd dim) indices respectively

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
sum([sum(row) - (row[i] if len(row) < i else 0) for i,row in enumerate(X)])
```

It runs over every row in the 2d array, and sums it, then take out the `i` cell (if exists) so it won't get into sum